# jmeter recorder, best strategy to filter dross and separate pages

Tags: jmeter

We want to load test a site which has 200+ requests per page, and most of them are generated by javascript, so not picked up if you ask jmeter to just load a page and its requests (as it doesnt "see" requests made in js).

This we are trying to use the recorder.

When you setup jmeter recorder proxy (and CA) on a mac, and start recording, and record say hitting 5 different pages of your site:

1. It picks up a ton of garbage, unrelated to the actual pages you are trying to record. This includes skype, outlook, stuff chrome does in the background etc.
2. It merges all the request for all pages you hit into one long list, making it impossible to put different timings between pages etc.

Questions:

1. Is there a better way to record a number of pages on the site than Using the jmeter proxy on a mac?  Perhaps windows has options which do not record the OS garbage for example?
2. what is a good strategy to filtering out the garbage?

   1. Going through every page of our site using chrome dev tools, and write down every domain hit.  In the jmeter recorder whitelist those domains.
   2. use referer in filter?
   3. go through every request recorded and output in the jmeter results tree, and write an exclude pattern for each?
   4. other ideas?
3. how can I separate the "pages" so I can change the timings between each page?  Perhaps I should record each page individually, then try to merge them into one jmx?

Note: our site loads requests from about 20 different sources, not just our own domain.  These sources could change any time (e.g. if developer adds a new js library).

Answer (score 0):

1. To exclude "OS Garbage" use a browser which has separate proxy configuration, [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) and derivatives rely on operating-system wide proxy therefore JMeter catches each and every HTTP request using this proxy. A good example of a browser with independent proxy and certificates configuration is [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
2. The best strategy to filter out the "garbage" is focusing only on your domain(s), the others can be excluded from recording/load testing using "URL Patterns to Exclude" section (lives under "Requests Filtering" tab of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder))

   [image]

   I don't think you need to load test all these 20 different sources (unless they are integral parts of your application), see [Excluding Domains from the Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for comprehensive explanation and example filters
3. When you start recording you will see this window:

   [image]

   where you can give your transactions meaningful names and also define an "idle" time so JMeter will consider it as a start of the next logical business transaction

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info.  Regarding the transactions control - I dont get this - If I want to record say hitting 10 pages, this will all be one giant list of requests - its not a transaction but a visit.  I cant find any way to record separate pages and combine them into one script, so that I can say vary the time between each page being hit, or record the total response time for each page. Is any of this possible?